# Calling external rest api from Splunk search query

Tags: splunk, splunk-query

I am looking for if there is anyway I can call an external REST api (GET call, sample url shown below) from the Splunk search query panel, parse the JSON response and display in a table.

```
https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts
```

Does Splunk allow this, directly from Search query without using any plugins/add-ons?